# Why does the MAP_SHARED flag make other processes immediately visible?

Tags: mmap

```c
void* mmap(void* start,size_t length,int prot,int flags,int fd,off_t offset);
```

When using the `mmap` method, the flags parameter is `MAP_SHARED`. Everyone says that a process modification makes other processes visible immediately, so why are other processes visible immediately?
Don't consider the CPU cacheline?

Answer (score 1):

The changes are not necessarily visible *immediately*.  In any multi-threaded scenario, you have to employ proper memory synchronization/ordering facilities.  This typically involves atomic operations and associated memory fences, and it's these operations that resolve synchronization around cache coherency, write-back buffers, etc.

For detail's on memory order semantics in "C" have a look [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/memory_order).